# Automatic OpenAPI generation in Spring with multipart requests

Tags: java, spring, multipartform-data, openapi, springdoc

I have a problem with the OpenAPI generator in a spring boot application generating the definition of a REST endpoint that accepts a multipart request.

When I am explicitly defining the parts like shown below. It generates an OpenAPI definition that is working/valid when used in for example in Azure API Management.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public List<String> upload(@RequestPart MultipartFile file, @RequestPart UploadMetaData data) {

  . . .

}
```

```
paths:
  /api/v1/upload:
    post:
      operationId: upload
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              required:
              - data
              - file
              type: object
              properties:
                gatewayId:
                  type: string
                file:
                  type: string
                  format: binary
                data:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/UploadMetaData'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            '*/*':
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  type: string
```

But when I am trying to use `MultipartRequest` instead of the annotated -`File`, the controller itself is still working as expected accepting an arbitrary list of multipart segments when I call it directly, but the OpenAPI definition that is generated is not reflecting the actual interface because it is trying to use the `request` parameter as an URL path parameter, so when I import this spec into Azure API Management it is not working.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public List<String> upload(MultipartRequest request) {

  . . .

}
```

```
paths:
  /api/v1/upload:
  post:
    operationId: upload
    parameters:
    - name: request
      in: query
      required: true
      schema:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/MultipartRequest'
    requestBody:
      content:
        multipart/form-data:
          schema:
            type: string
    responses:
      "200":
        description: OK
        content:
          '*/*':
            schema:
              type: array
              items:
                type: string
```

Other than giving my API a name, I didn't configure anything special for the generator:

```
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My REST API", version = "1.0"))
public class MySpringApplication {

. . . 

}
```

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
  <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Is this a bug or am I missing some annotation or other configuration here?

Comment: Hi, did you get a chance to fix this issue. I am also facing the same, it would be helpful if you can answer.

Comment: I am working around this issue in that I only use MultipartFile at the moment and avoiding MultipartRequest completely

Answer (score 0):

The `MultipartRequest`, is not supported out of the box.
You can use the following code to enable the support.

```
static{
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().addFileType(MultipartRequest.class);
}
```

This support will be added for the future release.

Comment: Tried this in `ApplicationStartUp.java` in spring boot v2.6.6. Not working as stated in the answer.

Comment: a little late but same here, adding this static block to my application startup doesn't change anything in the specs for me. running on springdoc-openapi 1.6.6 now.